# R shinydashboard

Tags: r, shiny

here is my Q:
I have a textinput widget in shiny ui, which is supposed to get a series of data entry, for example, 1,2,3,4,5,6 and then on the server.r I want to operate on this entry like plotting, doing some math and etc. 
the problem is that R consider the WHOLE ENTRY as a character and it is like "1,2,3,4,5,6" and I can not change the data type into numeric!
Please Help!

Comment: Any reason you need it as textInput? Why not a range Input, see here: http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/sliders.html?

Answer (score 0):

Strsplit creates a list and we access the first element of it (but there's only 1).

as.integer converts this into an integer list

```
  myArray = as.integer(strsplit("1,2,3,4,5,6", ",")[[1]])
```

Output:

```
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Comment: thanks for your kind reply, but, THE WHOLE entry is a character and is like "1,2,3,4,5,6"